Switch back to old Windows Calendar
How do I switch to the old Windows Calendar in August 2024?
I don't like the "New Outlook", I don't like Outlook in general. Previously, you could just opt out of the "New Outlook". This option kind of still exists as described in this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/toggle-out-of-the-new-outlook-for-windows-preview-ec102b39-5727-418e-ae1f-a1805434640c. However, it works only temporarily and only for Mail. I don't care about the old Mail App too much. But I really want the old Calendar App back, as it is very lightweight compared to Outlook. Of course, I could use a third party calendar app that is better than outlook, but there is one feature that I would miss. Clicking on an event in the little time and date thingy on the Windows taskbar. Interestingly, this does briefly open the old calendar app, but it immediately closes again, probably attempting to open the New Outlook.
Does anyone know how to convince it to actually open?

You cannot; The change was permanent.

You can use the old Calendar app if the new Outlook is uninstalled. However, Windows will automatically reinstall the new Outlook regularly—and even each time you open the old Calendar.
As a workaround to keep using the old Calendar without being redirected to the new Outlook, you can create a shortcut that first uninstalls the new Outlook and then opens the old Calendar app.
Here’s how:

Right-click on your desktop and select New > Shortcut.

In the location field, enter the following:


powershell -Command "Get-AppxPackage *Outlook* | Remove-AppxPackage; Start-Process 'outlookcal:'"



Click Next, give your shortcut a name (e.g., "Calendar"), and click Finish.

Now, each time you want to open the classic Calendar app, double-click this shortcut. You can also move this shortcut to a folder indexed by Windows search to easily locate it in the Start Menu or Windows Search.

Resetting the app in the Windows settings did the trick.
Probably only temporarily, but for now it works for me.

To switch back to the old Calendar App, here are some steps you may try:

Toggle Off New Outlook: In the upper-right corner of the Outlook window, there should be a toggle to switch off the "New Outlook". This might help in reverting to the classic Calendar app.

Registry Edit: You can try editing the Windows Registry to disable the New Outlook and revert to the classic version. This method requires caution as incorrect changes to the registry can cause system issues.

Uninstall New Outlook: Another option is to uninstall the New Outlook app and create a desktop shortcut to the classic Outlook app.

Use the Classic View: Navigate to the Outlook menu, uncheck the option for the New Outlook, and click the Revert button. This should allow the application to revert to the classic Outlook view.


In addition, i found a similar thread that you may feel free to refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1380368/how-to-go-back-for-a-old-ms-outlook
Hope it helps!

This looks like an AI generated answer
